Forecast calibration with a general explanatory factor
I'm thinking of making a set of probability-based prediction for the coming 2 years of the Trump administration. The prediction will be a set of propositions like:

There will be a federal ban on abortion, 20%.

The idea is to test my calibration, i.e. ideally 20% of my 20% prediction should come to pass, 50% of my 50% predictions, etc.
When trying to think through my predictions I quickly ran into the potential problem that the predictions all share a common factor - my estimation of DJTs character. Maybe he's mostly interested in winning elections and getting applause, in which case enacting his policy agenda might turn into almost nothing. Or he's a visionary, previously held back by various adults in the room that won't be around this time. If this line of thinking is correct there's a risk I'd either get all wrong in one direction or the other. (which I feel would unfairly screw up my calibration, given that I saw this problem coming).
My question is whether someone has a suggestion for how I could integrate this common factor into my set of predictions?
My first thought has been to specify every predictions relationship to this factor, and if one prediction comes true that will then increase the probability of all other predictions (by some amount specified per proposition). When trying to work out the details for how to do this I unfortunately got stuck. Does anyone have a suggestion for how I could do this, or could point me to someone having done a similar thing?
